# PHP Wordpress set custom taxomy to value of custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, field

I have set a value to a custom field: `cf_merk`
Now I need to pass that value to a custom taxonomy `ct_cars_mer` (slug: `merk-categorie`)

I have made custom fields for a car dealer website. One of the custom fields is `cf_merk`. ("merk"stands for "brand")
Now it's time to build a filter so people can for instance look at only all Porsches. But filtering can only be done with Custom Taxonomies as far as I understand. So the car dealer fills in the custom field `cf_merk` and automatically the custom taxonomy should become the same.
I tried lots of variations of these:

```php
$ct_cars_mer = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cf_merk', true);
echo $ct_cars_mer;
```

or

```php
$cf_merk = "merk-categorie_$catIdChild";
echo $ct_cars_mer . "ct cars?";
echo $cf_merk . "ct merk?";
```

Comment: You can use the meta_query for the custom field for the filters.

Comment: I assume you're referring to the filter. I have the filter working. It works with Custom taxonomies that i filled in manually. I only need the PHP to transfer the value of the custom field to the custom taxonomy. Simply said: ct_cars_mer = cf_merk